# How to make a container responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making my first react website and split a page in half. It works good when it is full-screen but when I make the window smaller, it looks bad. Here is an example in full screen:
[image: full screen]

And here it is half screen. [image: half screen]

So I basically want half screen to look like the first, except I want it to overflow right below the picture. I just don't want any white space under the picture. How to achieve this?
Here is the code:

```
<div className="splitScreen">
          <div className="leftPane">
            <img
              className='nedirp'
              alt='covid test kiti nedir'
              src='images/test-nedir.jpg'
            />
          </div>
          <div className="rightPane">
            <p >Vücudumuzun savunma mekanizmasında bulunan ve vücumuzdaki zararlı virüs ve bakteriler ile savaşan Y şekilli proteinlere antikor ya da tıbbi ismi ile immünoglobulin denir. Bu antikorların tespiti için kullanılan tıbbi cihazlara ise Antikor Testi denir.</p>
            <h1>ANTİKOR TESTİ KİMLERE UYGULANABİLİR?</h1>
            <p>Vücudunda zararlı bakteri ya da virüs bulunduğu süphelenen kişilerde kullanılır. Koronavirüs pandemisiyle gündeme gelen antikor testleri pandemi sürecinde tüm kurumlara büyük kolaylık sağlamıştır.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the css that I currently have

```
.splitScreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.leftPane {
  width: 50%;
}

.rightPane {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: At what viewport width does the page start to break? You need to use a media query at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using bootstrap. I also recommend using rem instead of pixels. (Turkish comment: kolay gelsin)

```
<div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <img
              className='img-fluid'
              alt='covid test kiti nedir'
              src='images/test-nedir.jpg'
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <p >Vücudumuzun savunma mekanizmasında bulunan ve vücumuzdaki zararlı virüs ve bakteriler ile savaşan Y şekilli proteinlere antikor ya da tıbbi ismi ile immünoglobulin denir. Bu antikorların tespiti için kullanılan tıbbi cihazlara ise Antikor Testi denir.</p>
            <h1>ANTİKOR TESTİ KİMLERE UYGULANABİLİR?</h1>
            <p>Vücudunda zararlı bakteri ya da virüs bulunduğu süphelenen kişilerde kullanılır. Koronavirüs pandemisiyle gündeme gelen antikor testleri pandemi sürecinde tüm kurumlara büyük kolaylık sağlamıştır.</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, saol

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a media query at the point where the design starts to break.

For eg:

```
.splitScreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.leftPane {
  width: 50vw;
}

.rightPane {
  width: 50vw;
}

/* Change 992px as required */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .splitScreen {
    display: block;
  }
}
```